# Ruby DataMapper not saving property set in before hook

Tags: ruby, datamapper

```
class Order
  include Datamapper::Resource

  property :birthday_day, String  
  property :birthday_month, String
  property :birthday_year, String
  property :birthday, Date

  before :save do
    @birthday = Date.new(@birthday_year.to_i, @birthday_month.to_i, @birthday_day.to_i)
  end
end
```

It's a part of model, but it's enouth.
When save field (from irb or from sinatra application) :birthday not save in DB. But in irb, i see object, where :birthday exist and it Date format.
When change field manual (from irb):
f.birthday = Date.new
f.save
In object and in DB result appear (in obj as Date obj, in DB as "2010-2-3")

Help me please to understand, what wrong with before in model.

Sorry for my not good enlish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use property mutator method. Setting the ivar doesn't trigger dirty tracking. Just do this:

```
self.birthday = Date.new(birthday_year.to_i, birthday_month.to_i, birthday_day.to_i)
```

Also it would be better to use Integer as the property type for year, month and day.

Answer (score 3):

DataMapper documentation recommends [#attribute_set](http://rdoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/master/DataMapper/Resource%3aattribute_set)

> Sets the value of the attribute and marks the attribute as dirty if it has been changed so that it may be saved. Do not set from instance variables directly, but use this method.

In your case:

```
before :save do
  set_attribute(:birthday => Date.new(self.birthday_year.to_i, self.birthday_month.to_i, self.birthday_day.to_i))
end
```

For what it's worth, unless I needed to use all the fields in SELECT criteria, I would save either the integer fields or the date, not both:

```
class Order
  include Datamapper::Resource

  property :birthday, Date
end

# change month
o = Order.create(:birthday => Date.new(...))
o.update(:birthday => Date.new(o.birthday.year, new_month, o.birthday.mday))
```

Or

```
class Order
  include Datamapper::Resource

  property :birthday_day, String  
  property :birthday_month, String
  property :birthday_year, String

  def birthday
    if self.birthday_day && self.birthday_month && self.birthday_year
      Date.new(self.birthday_day, ...)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: self.birthday=(v) and attribute_set(:birthday, v) do the same thing except the former returns resource's state object and the latter the value which was set.

Comment: Good point @solnic. I usually prefer the _set, _get methods because, in addition to the doc's statement, I find it easier to read as I know there's nothing else happening if I see `_set(:foo...)`, but `self.foo = x` will sometimes be overridden with additional behavior that may or may not be desirable.) Then again, _set isn't as succinct.